# Exchange not allowing connections every 2 days at 4am

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange

I am currently having an issue with Exchange crashing every 2 days at roughly 4:42AM. The exchange services are running but Outlook will not connect to the server. Also, in the application log, I have tons of failed attempts by iPhone users.

I checked the application log for any warnings/errors that may give me some clue of whats going on, but nothing is there.

If I attempt to connect via OWA, I get: HTTP status code: [503]. Verify that the Exchange mailbox Server is working correctly.

I am at a loss right now and I am not sure where to move from here. A simple reboot will 'fix' the problem, but I know it will just go down again.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Exchange are you using?

What do you mean by "crashing"? Are you seeing one of the Exchange services stopping, or are you just making a general statement about some kind of availabilty problem?

My gut says that your "Information Store" service is being stopped, either because of an unhandled exception, or because something is stopping it. Watch the "System" and "Application" event logs to see if there's any evidence of the MSExchangeIS service stopping. Be sure to look at the "Services" list and see if all the Exchange-related services that are marked for "Automatic" startup are still listed as "Started".

I suspect you'll find the "Information Store" service stopped, and I suspect that re-starting it will alleviate the symptom. If that is the case, determining the root cause will require more information. One thing is certain: If the IS is crashing I'd be *certain* that I had good backups ASAP. The database engine behind Exchange, ESE, is a really nice and very solid database engine. If it's crashing there's probably a hardware problem or filesystem corruption on the volume hosting the database or transaction logs.

Answer (score 0):

Check the IIS logs on your Client Access Server you can find them at. C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles\W3SVC1. Something else to look at is since you're getting a 503 is there anything that would be eating up all of the resources on your CAS server. Most likely a backup running.

You might also want to check the logs under C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles\HTTPERR and see if you see any error messages along the lines of "Connection_Abandoned_By_AppPool MSExchangeSyncAppPool"